# Orchstrate database Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

My code:

```
app.get ('/attend/', function(req, res) {

  db.merge ('Event', 'key', {

    'attendants': fbName(req, res)

  });

});
```

I get this error message: TypeError: db.merge is not a function

Anyone knows how to use merge function using orchestrate?

Comment: var db = require('orchestrate')(config.db);

Comment: And it's defined in the same file as your route?

Comment: Yes it is, both are implemented in index.js

Comment: What does this return when you run it on the command line? `node -pe "typeof require('orchestrate')('abc').merge"`

Comment: It returns undefined

Comment: That's not right, it returns `function` for me (using `orchestrate@0.8.0`), as expected. What does this return? `node -pe "require.resolve('orchestrate')"`

Comment: This: /BikeBuddy2/node_modules/orchestrate/index.js

Comment: In that case, you may be using an outdated version. Try installing the latest: `npm i orchestrate@latest --save`

Comment: What version of orchestrate are you using?

Comment: Yes it worked! Just wrong version...